# Cython in visual studio 2013

Tags: python, windows, visual-studio, visual-c++, cython

My python background is unix (mac os and ubuntu). I recently heard about a Python plugin for VS and though this `could` be awesome because i like Windows ;-). The plugin is only awailable in the 2013 version so i installed it and then i tried to install cython over the integrated GUI command line interface where you can install packages over pip or easy_install, which is pretty neat.

It failed, `error: Microsoft Visual C++ 10.0 is required (Unable to find vcvarsall.bat).` after some research it seems like i would have to install visual c++ from the 2008 version?

Im a bit confused i have visual studio installed and with it the visual studio c++. Im really not used to windows, so could anyone who understands this give me some directions please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok this is a bit of an error on my part. Cython doesn't support Windows.

[Cython.org](http://cython.org) links to [this](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#cython) in its [download section](http://cython.org/#download).

> Christoph Gohlke has created Windows installers available for download on [his site](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#cython).

After you downloaded the wheel file you just install it with pip into the environment(virtual or global) you want and you are good to go.

```
 pip install <path-to-download.whl>
```

or enter the path to the .whl file into the VS pip GUI.

Answer (score 0):

Set the VS90COMNTOOLS environment variable.

```
SET VS90COMNTOOLS=%VS120COMNTOOLS%
```